# Custom Browser Authentication Dialog

Tags: html, authentication, browser, popup, password-protection

I have set up some password protected directories on my website. They work fine, but a pretty ugly pop-up window is displayed when the end user is prompted to enter their username and password. Is there an easy way to go about using a form I built/styled rather than the browsers default? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to be certain what you're seeing but I'm guessing that you're seeing the basic authentication dialog. Exactly what this looks like will vary by the browser, its version, and OS you're running on.

The alternative to that is what's called "forms authentication". This is where you show an HTML page that has input fields for the user to enter their credentials and login. You configure forms authentication on the server. The exact details vary widely by the server-side technology you are using. If you google "forms authentication iis" (replace "IIS" with "apache", "tomcat", or whatever your server is) you'll find instructions on enabling it. You should be able to find source HTML you can just copy-and-paste into your application and then modify the look-and-feel to have your website name on it or whatever you want.